# Putting input fields in an image

Tags: html, css, image, textfield

I have an image that looks like this:

([can't embed images yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdKiM.png))

I want to add a field to each line relative to the text and add a button to the center of the bottom of the image. IE:

```
First name: [First name here]
Last name:  [Last name here ]
Email:      [Email address  ]

      [Submit button]
```

My problem is I don't how to do this, I have tried doing it like so:

```
<style>
    .input-image {
        background: url("images/INPUT_GRAPHIC.png");
        min-height: 380px;
        background-position: left;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: unset;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }  
    .btn {
        background-color: #565258;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px 20px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        opacity: 0.9;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .btn:hover {
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>
<div class="bg-image"></div>
<div class="input-image">
    <form action="/form_to_email.php">
        <div class="input-img">
            <div class="containter">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="first_name" class="first-name-input" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="last_name" class="last-name-input" required>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" class="email-address-input" required>
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit to be inspired</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="info-image">
    <img src="images/INFO_GRAPHIC2.png"/>
</div>
```

But this does not diplay the correct way, how can I go about adding the fields next to the appropriate text in the picture?

Comment: You want to add the input fields on top of the image? If so, your best bet would probably be using absolute positions on the fields, or maybe just their container if the desired space between the fields is uniform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do what you want to. You can use absolute position, you can wrap your label and input content into one div, section and etc.

For position absolute you can for example use this approach below to center the inputs and button to the screen;

```
.container {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

In order to have input field next to the text label you can add the tag

```
<label for="enter-first-name">Enter Fist name</label>
<input id="enter-first-name" type="text" name="first_name" class="first-name-input" required>
```

It is important to add the id for the input and the for property in order to the label knows which input it should be render next to.

If you want the label and input to use an entire line. 
You can add display: block to you input and float: left to make the label goes to the left of the input.

```
input { 
    display: block; 
}

label {
    float: left;
}
```

As a best practice you should use the class name used on the input and label and not just input on css. Using the "input" and "label" in your css file will make all your inputs and labels behave at the same way. Instead use the class name.

**EDIT**

At this link you can find a lot of help to center div on screen.
It goes beyond what is necessary but definitely can help you on centering stuff.
[CSS-trick Centering CSS complete guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)